# Why do I have to add an assignment sign in C++ to declare an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question about the syntax in C++ when it comes to declaring arrays. I watched a tutorial where someone used the following code to create the array, but I get errors when running it.

It seems like I can only run the code if I include an `=` between the `[]` and the values of the array. Please explain why he doesn't get compiling issues as I did.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    char vowels[] {'a' ,'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    cout << "\nThe first vowel is: " << vowels[0] << endl;
    cout << "The last vowel is: " << vowels[4] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp:10:10: error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer

  char vowels[] {'a' ,'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
              ^
main.cpp:10:18: error: expected ';' at end of declaration

  char vowels[] {'a' ,'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
               ^

2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Please show the error messages that you get.

Comment: Why not just `const char* vowels = "aeiou";`? The end result is effectively the same, but with way less junk.

Comment: @tadman Would be fine in this case, but that isn't exactly equivalent. In OP's case you could do `vowels[1] = 'x';` which doesn't work with your alternative.

Comment: @AndroYono Please share how you are compiling this. Which compiler, which version and which compilation flags are being used?

Comment: It seems your compiler or compilation mode is too old. Use compilers that support C++11 and enable C++11.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think it's fairly safe to presume that consonants are *constant*.

Comment: The code you posted only becomes legal with C++11. You should enable that in your build.

Comment: Why is the syntax of the language the way it is? Well, because that's the way it's defined. Like it or not.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766)

Answer (score 3):

The way you're trying to declare the array:

```
char vowels[] {'a' ,'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

is called extended initializer lists and it's only available from C++11 and above. Ensure your compiler supports this version and above. You may manually use `-std=c++11` flag when compiling to verify (since it's not clear which version you're currently using to compile):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
```

**Note:** It'll work when you use an assignment operator `=` to assign it which is supported by old compilers:

```
char vowels[] = {'a' ,'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way I can set the default compiler version to c++11 without typing it in the comand line every time?

Comment: @AndroYono Look into *makefiles* and/or CMake.

Comment: It should be pointed out as well that there is no reason not to use `-std=c++17` instead of the much older C++11 revision.